# Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, qpython3

Guys am trying to install OpenCV 3.3.1 on Raspbian stretch Noobs on Pi model B
I am following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/) tutorial.

But when i type

```
cmake
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH= ~/Opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=yes \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=OFF.. `
```

And then i type `make -j2`

To get this error

```
[  7%] building cxx object 3rsparty/openexr/CMakeFiles/IlmImf.dir/IlmImf/    ImfZipcompressor.cpp.o
[  7%] linking cxx static library.. /lib/libIlmImf.a
[  7%] built target IlmImf
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was in this line

```
/home/pi/opencv3.3.1/3rdparty/carotene/src/absdiff.cpp:42:22: fatal error: common.hpp: no such file or directory
 #include "common.hpp"
```

I 've gone through the directory and opened  absdiff.cpp to find `#include "common.hpp"` 
But no file called common.hpp in the same directory so i copied common.hpp from
/home/pi/opencv/3rd party/carotene/src/
Which i cloned using this code
    git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git opencv

I don't know why opencv-3.3.1 doesn't have it or just an issue during the download...

Or just re-download opencv-3.3.1 again